# Relacion entre tablas Join

Tags: php, html, mysql, join

Estoy tratando de hacer un `JOIN` (es la primera vez) y tengo este código pero me muestra los siguientes errores.

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario\int.php on line 5
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\inventario\int.php on line 7

```
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_usuarios, nombre, ap, am, fecha, localidad, departamento FROM usuarios";
$res =mysqli_query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

    $option.="option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[nombre] </option>";   
    $option.="option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[ap] </option>";
    $option.="option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[am] </option>";
    $option.="option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[fecha] </option>";
    $option.="option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[localidad] </option>";
    $option.="option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[departamento] </option>";
}
?>

<select>
<option value="-">Selecciona el usuario</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
```

Archivo **connect_db.php**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new MySQLi("", "","", "");
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
  die( "Fallo la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_errno() . ") " . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_error());
} else //echo "Conexión exitossa!";

//  $link =mysqli_connect("localhost","","");
//  if($link){
//  mysqli_select_db($link,"academ");
// }
?>
```

Comment: No colocaste el error que te sale; pero prueba en vez de $row[id_usuarios] sea $row['id_usuarios']; que $row[nombre] sea $row['nombre'] y así con los demás.

Comment: Los datos que se almacenan

Comment: Esta toda mi conexión a mi base de datos

Comment: <?php


  $mysqli = new MySQLi("", "","", "");
  if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
   die( "Fallo la conexión a MySQL: (" . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_errno() 
    . ") " . $mysqli -> mysqli_connect_error());
  }
  else
   //echo "Conexión exitossa!";

// $link =mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
// if($link){
//  mysqli_select_db($link,"academ");
// }
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Errores:

- Viendo tu archivo `connect_db.php`, podemos ver que has decidio usar el estilo `Orientado a objeto` de la libreria [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.construct.php). Pero al ejecutar tanto el `query` como el `fetch`, estas usando el estilo por `procedimientos`
- En el bucle `while`, no has abierto correctamente los tags `options`

Soluciones:

- Decidirse por un estilo, en este caso voy a optar por el `orientado a objeto`, es por esto que vamos a usar:

  - `$mysqli->query` en lugar de `mysqli_query`.
  - `$res->fetch_assoc()` en lugar de `mysqli_fetch_array`.
- Abrir correctamente los `option`, es decir, `<option...`

Ejemplo:

```html
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_usuarios, nombre, ap, am, fecha, localidad, departamento FROM usuarios";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[nombre] </option>";   
    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[ap] </option>";
    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[am] </option>";
    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[fecha] </option>";
    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[localidad] </option>";
    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_usuarios]\">$row[departamento] </option>";
}
?>

<select>
<option value="-">Selecciona el usuario</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Si la idea del `select` es que se puede _"Selecciona el usuario"_, no entiendo porque quieres generar un `option` para el `nombre`, otro para el `ap`, etc. cuando con uno solo alcanza.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu consejo y por las correcciones, fue la solución a mi problema de código.